# Can you have more than one of the same technology in Ticket to Ride: UK?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom

In Ticket to Ride: UK, can one player get more than one of the same technology card to prevent other players from getting them - for example when 4 players are playing can one player get all 4 mechanical stokers to stop other players from getting 3 train routes?  It is not clear in the rules.

Comment: I admire this strategy, but it does not seem to be within the accepted rules.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, it doesn't actually answer this in the rulebook, however the designer of the game Alan R. Moon answered this question [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1456138/article/20663097#20663097).

> You cannot have two of the same Technology Card.
>
> Alan R. Moon